Live activity with activity kit is not refreshin on archive build
I have live activities in one part of application and all i do is start it through singleton which is manager for live activity. Than main app goes to background but live activity start counter. Everything work when i build on physical device on xcode but when i build with archive and distribute with firebase live activity starts and immediately timer in it stuck. Timer continue when app goes in foreground. Timer should still be active even if app is in background because its tied to another target(widget in this case) which is always active because of live activity. Here is part of code for manager class in widget target that handles live acivitiy.
final class LiveActivityManager {
    private var activityID: String?
    private var currentContentState: BloomDiagnosticsWidgetAttributes.ContentState?
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var secondsElapsed: Int = 0
    
    static let shared = LiveActivityManager()

    func startActivity(titleInProgress: String,titleFinished:String, subtitle: String) {
        endCurrentActivityAsync()
        startNewActivity(title: titleInProgress, subtitle: subtitle + "00 m 00 s")
        startTimerForLiveActivity(titleInProgress:titleInProgress,titleFinished:titleFinished,subtitle:subtitle)
    }

    func startTimerForLiveActivity(titleInProgress: String,titleFinished:String, subtitle: String) {
        secondsElapsed = 0
        let totalTimeInSeconds = 30
        
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 15.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            self.secondsElapsed += 1
            
            let minutes = self.secondsElapsed / 60
            let seconds = self.secondsElapsed % 60
            let timeString = String(format: subtitle + "%02d m %02d s", minutes, seconds)

            let progress = min(Float(self.secondsElapsed) / Float(totalTimeInSeconds), 1.0)
            
            self.updateActivity(title: titleInProgress, subtitle: timeString, progresValue: progress, measuringState: .INPROGRESS)

            if self.secondsElapsed >= totalTimeInSeconds {
                self.timer?.invalidate()
                self.updateActivity(title: titleFinished, subtitle: "", progresValue: 1.0, measuringState: .COMPLETED)
            }
        }
    }
... rest of code for updating and dismissing live activity ...

}

